# Arcgis api modules are can not be loaded

Tags: javascript, dojo, arcgis, esri

I am writing code for developing interactive maps using the ArcGIS API and Dojo classes.

It works fine, until I define some modules such as "esri/toolbars/draw" or some other modules. These give an error: *http://localhost/esri/toolbars/draw.js 404 (Not Found)*

My question is, if I am using many other modules such as 'dojo/_base/declare', 'dojo/_base/lang', 'dojo/on', 'dojo/Deferred', 'esri/map' and many others, why can the program not load 'esri/toolbars/draw'? Interestingly, it searches for it in localhost, which is not the right place to look since I am not using the ArcGIS API locally.

I am wondering if someone can kindly help me with this. Below is a sample of my code:

```
require({
async: true,
parseOnLoad: true,
baseUrl: "/myApp/",
aliases: [
['text', 'dojo/text']
],
packages: [{
name: 'controllers',
location: 'js/controllers'
}, {
name: 'services',
location: 'js/services'
}, {
name: 'utils',
location: 'js/utils'
}, {
name: 'widgets',
location:  'js/widgets'
}, {
name: 'app',
location: 'js',
main:'main'
}]
}, ['app']);
___________________________________________ widgets/edit/drawTools.js
define([
'dojo/_base/declare',
'dojo/_base/lang',
'dojo/on',
'dijit/_WidgetBase',
'dijit/_TemplatedMixin',
'dojo/dom-class',
'text!widgets/edit/drawTools.html',
'esri/graphic',
"esri/toolbars/draw",
"esri/symbols/SimpleMarkerSymbol", 
"esri/symbols/SimpleLineSymbol",
"esri/symbols/PictureFillSymbol",     
"esri/symbols/CartographicLineSymbol",
"esri/Color"
    ], function(
    declare, lang, on, _WidgetBase, _TemplatedMixin, domClass, template,      graphic, Draw, SimpleMarkerSymbol, SimpleLineSymbol,
    PictureFillSymbol, CartographicLineSymbol, Color
    ) {


        return declare([_WidgetBase, _TemplatedMixin], {

            templateString: template,
            map:null,
            options:{},

            constructor: function(options) {
                this.options = options;
                this.map = this.options.map;
            },

            postCreate: function() {
                tb = new Draw(this.map);
                tb.on("draw-end", '_addGraphic');
            }

            function _addGraphic(evt) {
        }
        })
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

Your runtime configuration for dojo is not correct. Please refer the documentation. [here](https://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.10/modules_advanced/)

> Note that not all configuration options can be set at runtime. In
>   particular, async, tlmSiblingOfDojo, and pre-existing has tests cannot
>   be changed once the loader is loaded. Additionally, most configuration
>   data is shallow copied, which means that you couldn’t use this
>   mechanism to, for example, add more keys to a custom configuration
>   object—the object would be overwritten

Try to use the default way of adding dojoConfig. Also, dojoConfig must be added before adding the esri api url.

```
<script>
    dojoConfig= {
        parseOnLoad: true,
        async: true
        package: [{
            "name": "agsjs",
            "location": location.pathname.replace(/\/[^/]+$/, "")+'/agsjs'
          }]
    };
</script>
```

Dojo api is part of esri api so adding explicit url for dojo is not required.

Comment: Glad I could help, Please mark the question as answered.